# Get a cryptographically strong random number?

Tags: api, random, cryptography, erlang

How do I get a cryptographically strong random number in Erlang, equivalent to reading from /dev/random on Unix?

So far I've only seen recommendations to use random:uniform and seed it with something like now() which is not strong enough.

(Yes, I'm aware that it's pseudo-random on BSDs, but apparently they consider it good enough, and if it's not, it's their problem).

Comment: How strong does it need to be then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is even better: [crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#strong_rand_bytes-1)

It *uses a cryptographically secure prng seeded and periodically mixed with operating system provided entropy.*

If you want to convert the bytes into an integer, try `crypto:bytes_to_integer(crypto:strong_rand_bytes(N))` (`N` is the number of bytes you want to randomly generate).

A tip for using the `crypto` module: use the latest release of Erlang:)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [crypto:rand_bytes/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#rand_bytes-1) or [crypto:rand_uniform/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#rand_uniform-2)